# Laravel Eloquent whereIn return in order given

Tags: laravel, eloquent, where-in

I am trying to sort a collection by the order of an array passed by whereIn

My code:

```
Posts::whereIn('id', [80, 40, 30, 100])->get()
```

I am hoping for the collection to return the posts with ids in the order 80, 40, 30, 100 but instead it sorts into ascending order as 30, 40, 80, 100. How do I receive the results in the order I am hoping for?

Comment: use latest(). https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/queries#latest-oldest

Comment: $user->recent_posts()->latest('post_id')->get(); You can use this directly to get user posts.

Comment: Add more details to your question

Comment: Using latest() gives me the newest post instead of all posts in the order shown.

Comment: I have reworded my question to make it clear what my issue is

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this query -

```
$ids = [80, 40, 30, 100];
$implodedIds = implode(',', $ids);

Posts::whereIn('id', $ids)->orderByRaw(DB::raw("FIELD(id, $implodedIds)"))->get();
```